Is there a non-trivial arithmetic progression of positive integers such that every number contains the digit $2?$
Let $X:=\{$ positive integers that contain the digit $2\}$
For fixed $m,n\in\mathbb{N},$ define the A.P. $S_{m,n:=}\ \{m,\ m+n,\ m+2n, \ldots\}\ .$
I am interested in $S_{m,n}\cap X,$ and $S_{m,n}\cap (\mathbb{N}\setminus X).$
It is clear that $ S_{2,10}\subset X $ and so $\vert S_{2,10}\cap X\vert = \infty.$
Next, observe that $X$ has natural density $1$: In order for a number with $10^6$ digits to have  no $2'$s, the first digit must not be $2,$ ($8$ out of $9$ ways), and the next $999999$ digits must not be $2,$ ($9$ out of $10$ ways for each of the $999,999$ digits) - so $8*9^{999999}$ out of $9*{10}^{999999}.\quad \frac{8*9^{999999}}{ 9*{10}^{999999}}= \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)\left( \frac{9}{10} \right)^{999999} \approx 0.$ So relatively speaking, there are very few numbers with no digit $2.$
The question:
As already mentioned, there is a subset of $X$ that is an infinitely long A.P, for example, $S_{2,10}.$ Is there a non-trivial infinitely long A.P., $S_{m,n}$, that is also a subset of $X?$ $S_{2,10}$ is "trivial" because the last digit of all members of this A.P. is $2.$ Non-trivial, therefore, means that the $k-$th - last digit of every member of $S_{m,n},$ is not $2,$ for every $k.$ In other words, $2$ appears in every member of $S_{m,n},$ but it's place value keeps changing (more precisely, it isn't in the same position in every member of $X$.)
In all of the above, the number $2$ was arbitrary, and the answer is probably the same if we replace $2$ with any other digit.
I suspect the answer is yes, but that such a number will have a large amount of digits. On the other hand, the answer may be "no" due to some application of, for example, Dirichlet's approximation theorem.

One may assume without loss of generality that $n$ is not a multiple of $10$. If it is, then either the last digit of $m$ is $2$ (in which case $S_{m,n}$ is a "trivial" subset of $X$), or else the last digit of $m$ is not $2$ (in which case one could remove it from $m$ to get a new number $m'$ for which $S_{m',n/10}$ is still a subset of $X$).

@GeoffreyTrang good thinking.

So the last digit is not $0.$

I'm guessing that $x_{n+1}=x_n+10$ for $x_0=2$ is trivial by the standards of the question.

@controlgroup Yes, I specifically rule out this case. I suggest you read the body of the question carefully

Looking at $X = {2, 12, 20-29, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92, 102, 112, 120-129, ...}$, it's clear that $n \geq 10$. It won't help to pick $m$ large since e.g. $10^{10^{10}} + 2, 10^{10^{10}} + 12, ...$ are also elements of $X$. Ruling out multiples of 10, the candidate for smallest possible $n$ is one that takes us from $20\leq m+kn\leq 29$ to $120 \leq m+(k+2)n \leq 129$ in two steps, but this is easily ruled out. As is going from 20-29 to 120-129 in one step. My intuition is that all nontrivial $n$ can be ruled out in this fashion.

Every arithmetic sequence, in the nontrivial sense described by OP, contains a number whose digits are all $0$ or $1$.
I will show, if there is an $S_{m,n}\subset X$, then we may assume $n$ is coprime to $10$.  Then, take a subsequence, assume that $n=10^k-1$.   Then spread out all the digits of $m$, find an $m'$ in the sequence with all digits $0$ or $1$.
As noted by @GeoffreyTrang, we can assume $n$ is not a multiple of $10$.
If $n$ ends in $5$, then either $S_{m,2n}$ or $S_{m+n,2n}$ don't end in $2$.  So we can find $m'$ with $S_{m',n/5}\subset X$.  So we can assume $n$ is not a multiple of $5$.
Similarly we can assume $n$ is not a multiple of $2$.
Consider the remainders of powers of $10\pmod n$  Two of them must be equal, say $10^j=10^{j+k}\pmod n$.  $n$ is coprime to $10^j$ so there is a $p$ with $np=10^k-1$.  By taking a subsequence of our original $S$, let the new $n'=10^k-1$.
Write $$m=\sum 10^{a_i}\\ eg. 23=10+10+1+1+1$$
For example, if $n'=999$, then $20=10010\pmod{999}$ and $3=1001001\pmod{999}$.  So $23=1011011\pmod{999}$.  In this way, any number $m$ is equivalent $\pmod{10^k-1}$ to a number that contains only $0$s and $1$s.  This number is in the sequence.
This contradiction shows that no nontrivial $S_{m,n}$ is a subset of $X$.

I don't understand "If $n$ ends in 5, then either ${,2}$ or ${+,2}$ don't end in 2. So we can find $m'$ with $S_{m',n/5} \subset X$." Why is it enough to check that the last digit of the elements in these sets isn't 2? Don't you need something much stronger to conclude that the spacing $n$ between elements in $S_{m,n}$ can be reduced to $n/5$ (as it is in $S_{m',n/5}$)?

We have two sub-sequences $S_{m,2n}$ and $S_{m+n,2n}$.  $2n$ is a multiple of $10$  so we can chop off the final digit of both $m'$ and $2n$, like @GeoffreyTrang did, leaving a new sequence with $2n/10=n/5$.  Then keep dividing $n$ by $5$, and adjusting $m'$, until $n$ is no longer a multiple of $5$.

ah, I see. That's clever.

Took me awhile to understand this one, but I finally got it this afternoon. Key step I didn't get: to make sure the higher order terms are all 0 or 1 we add every higher values of $k$ in $10^k + 1$. Also, pick $k$ sufficiently large, so that $m$ has (perhaps several) fewer digits than $10^k$.
